# Как избежать ошибки 'A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated' в GridSearchCV при n_jobs = -1

Tags: python

Для подборки параметров использую GridSearchCV.
Код очень простой:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 200],     
    'max_depth': [10, 50, 100],
    'min_samples_split': [2, 4],
    'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2']
}
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 5, verbose = 5, n_jobs = -1)
grid.fit(X_train_t, y_train_t)
```

Проблема в том, что когда я запускаю код, получую ошибку:

```
TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker. The exit codes of the workers are {SIGKILL(-9)}
```

Причной этого есть `n_jobs = -1`. Когда я использую `n_jobs = 1`, все работает и нет ошибки. 
Как сделать так, чтобы код выполнялся при `n_jobs = -1`? Я хочу использовать все ядра для более быстрого обучения.

При использовании `n_jobs = 1`, боюсь, что мы будем учиться неделями :)

Спасибо)

Comment: Сколько у вас доступной и свободной  памяти и сколько занимает X_train_t ? Сколько у вас ядер CPU?

Comment: Свободной памяти - 32Gb, CPU = 16, X-train_t занимает 178Mb.

Comment: попробуйте эмпиричиским путем - начните с `n_jobs=14` и уменьшайте до тех пор пока не заработает...